# Android menu getItemId int comparison fails

Tags: java, android, menuitem

I wrote a little test program to try how popup menues work.
The menu is not static but dynamicly filled. The menu entries have the id 1 and 2.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_atctour_list);

    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabATCTourListAddTour);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(fab.getContext(), v);
            menu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Entry 1");
            menu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Entry 2");
            menu.show();

            menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    int i = item.getItemId();
                    if(i == 1) {
                        return true;
                    } else if(i == 2){
                            return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            });
        }});
}
```

In the onMenuItemClick method I tried to find out which entry has been selected. The result is that the if-clause is running allways into the else condition.

Debugging has shown that selecting item 1/2 generates id 1/2. The comparison with 1/2 never matches.

I dont't know what's wrong. Any help would be nice.

Comment: How did you test the conditions?

Comment: Agree with @CmosBattery  this might be debugger problem. You should add logs to print i variable.

Comment: I removed that comment as I'm confused by what the person is saying lol. Debugger might be wonky, but I originally thought that debugger was showing return true in the if but then returning false in the else. But I think its that the if nor the else if blocks are being entered. Could still be the debugger, but if i = 1 then the correct code block of i == 1 must execute.

Comment: When I run this code, I get the expected behavior (execution enters the correct `if` branch). I recommend doing a clean build, invalidating the Android Studio caches, or even restarting your computer.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. I found my mistake.

Comment: I put breakpoint at return true and false and this doesn't work. Now I put some toast info into the if branches and I have no problem anymore. I think a beginner's mistake. Thanks again